# How to install HAXM manually

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I am trying to install HAXM via SDK manager and end up with this error every time.

```
Unable to install Intel HAXM
Unknown Error
Please file a bug against Android Studio.
```

Complete log

```
Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_5_6.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" complete.
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" finished.
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.0\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.0-rc3\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0-rc1\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0-rc2\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-19\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-19\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-28\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-19\google_apis\armeabi-v7a\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis\x86\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
Android SDK is up to date.
Unable to install Intel HAXM
Unknown Error
Please file a bug against Android Studio.
Done
```

```
Packages to install: 
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)

Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_5_6.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in C:\Users\TEMBO MTOTO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" complete.
Failed to update status to COMPLETE
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
```

[image]
Several bug reports have already been submitted to google issue tracker. I was just looking for quick fix by installing it manually if it possible because I can't use emulator since yesterday. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as well..

Comment: @StefanJo just upgrade to the latest AS

Comment: sadly my Android Studio is already up to date and I still have the error...

Comment: @StefanJo then try uninstalling and installing everything from scratch